# Make all of the requested element this class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$("td").className='';
```

Trying to do something like this where it makes all the `<TD>` elements the requested css class. I don't even know if thats the proper way to do it.

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('td').addClass('yourClassName');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not used to using $() for elements and such.  I'll mark this as accepted when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$('td').attr('class', 'className');
```

Comment: This solution is what OP specified, though probably not what he wants.

Comment: Sure, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090991/benefits-of-using-attr-over-addclass-in-jquery) is a good explanation