# add "attribute" or Class to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on slideshow. At the end I want to add `current` class to my variable for next checking.

But that's not work, I also tried `attr` but not working.

this is my code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('.large_image').children('img').addClass('current');
        $('.product-item').click(function () {
            if ($('.large_image > img').hasClass('current')) {
                var $img = $(this).find('img').attr('data-img');
                var $slider = '<img class="dis-none" style="position:absulote;z-index:999" src=' + $img + ' />';
                $($slider).appendTo('.large_image').stop(true, true).delay(400).fadeIn(
                   function () {
                       $('.current').fadeOut(function () {
                           $(this).remove();

                       });
                   });
                $($slider).attr('class', 'current');
                $($slider).addClass('current');
            }
        })
    });
```

Any help on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your variable name is `$slider`, not `slider`. You'll need to add a `$` before `slider`: `$($slider)`. After fixing this, you can simply use jQuery's [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method:

```
$($slider).addClass('current');
```

jQuery also has a `removeClass()` method to remove the class, so before setting the new slide to "current", you may want to call:

```
$('.current').removeClass('current');
```

Comment: thanks for help but not working yet,i'm try `addClass` and `attr` also, but my problem not solved

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console? Are you sure the class isn't actually getting added to your `$slider` element?

Comment: no,i'm also add the alert and that show me: `<img class="dis-none" style="position:absulote;z-index:999" src=Images/slider/customer2.jpg />` and class `current` not added

Comment: Why don't you simply give it the "current" class when you first create the element? `var $slider = '<img class="dis-none current" ...`?

Comment: because in the next line i remove the previous slide,that has current class,at the end i should add new current class to next element;

Answer (score 1):

use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) to add a class attribute

```
$(slider).addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the actual mistake in your code.

```
$($slider).attr("class='current'"); //WRONG
$($slider).attr('class','current'); //RIGHT WAY
```

or simply using [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) method

```
$($slider).addClass('current');
```

Check this [Benefits of using attr() over addClass in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091115/1671639)

> **`addClass()`** has several benefits over manipulating the class with
> attr('class'):
>
> 1. It's semantically clearer.
> 2. It works with multiple classes.
> 3. It's apparently a lot faster.

Comment: thanks but not working yet,i'm add you code `addClass()` and `attr` but not working for me!

Answer (score 1):

use add class and remove class

```
$(slider).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
```

It also removes other elaments `current` class