# removeAtt slowly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery to select and manipulate SVG elements within the DOM. It's been tricky because I can do this adding or removing classes treating them as attributes.

Is it possible to remove an attribute using the animation effects from jQuery?

```
$('rect').mouseover(function(){    
    $(this).attr('class','selected');
});

$('rect').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('class');
});
```

Comment: Should be using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass` .. or better yet, `toggleClass()`.

Comment: You can't animate the `removeAttr` , although you can animate the effect of removeAttr.

Comment: You would need to animate the css properties to what they would be with the class removed.

Comment: No, that would imply that you can *half* remove an attribute, or 25% remove an attribute, or 10% add an attribute. You can't fractionally add or remove attributes. If you want something to animate, it needs to be something that can smoothly transition between states. The presence/absence of an attribute has only two states.

Comment: If you try the addClass, removeClass methods within a <svg> tag you'll see they don't work as they do with divs. This is the reason I am using .attr instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use ***[slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)*** or ***[slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)***

```
$(this).slideUp().removeAttr('class');
```

### Update:

```
$(this).slideUp().removeAttr('class').slideDown();
```

For this you will see some more effect

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/UDWJE/)**

Still you can do some more effects, for now I got this idea

### Update 2:

You can do using ***[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)*** and ***[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)*** too.

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('class').fadeIn('slow');
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/UDWJE/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, .addClass, .removeClass .toogleClass won't work in this context. I yet have to read if that's because I'm using SVG or what.

I got close to what I wanted via CSS, though:

```
.selected {
    fill: orange;
    -moz-transition: fill easeout .5s;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

This link was quite helpful as well: [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)