# jQuery .hasClass() method fails for SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a set of SVG elements with the classes `node` and `link`. My program should detect whether an element has the `node` class or the `link` class upon hovering over any of the SVG elements. However, for some reason, the `.hasClass()` doesn't seem to work:

```
$(".node").hover(function(evt){
    console.log($(this).attr("class")); //returns "node"
    console.log($(this).hasClass('node')); //returns false
}, function(){console.log("Done");});
```

So the element I hovered on has the class `node`, and jQuery detects that too, as shown by `console.log($(this).attr("class"));`, but for some reason the actual `.hasClass()` fails. Why is this? Is it failing because of the SVG?

Comment: just a side note, youre missing `);` in the end :) and, [seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/V4BNT/)

Comment: Interesting...try setting a variable equal to `$(this).attr("class")` then use `hasClass` with that var. Still false?

Comment: Elements inside SVG aren't really HTML, and as such there are properties missing from those elements, that's why getting the attribute works, but using hasClass, which probably checks the className property, does not work.

Comment: @hungerpain Ah thank you. I have that in my original code, but when I copied it to SO, I forgot it.

Comment: @adeneo Do you happen to know what I could use? My elements actually have multiple classes, so I cannot simply use `if($(this).attr("class") === "node"){//code here}` to check.

Comment: `$(this).attr("class").indexOf('node') != -1`

Comment: It's not really the same, but as long as none of the other classes contains the string "node" it would work.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! If you write up a formal answer, I would be more than happy to accept it. And that should work for my case.

Comment: I'm sure someone else will, I don't really need the rep, give it to someone else.

Comment: And remember that when working with SVG, the elements don't have stuff like className, innerHTML etc. so not everything in jQuery will work on those elements.

Comment: Definitely. I was trying to extract the content of a `<text>` element and spent a good 10 minutes before realizing that `innerHTML` wouldn't work.

Comment: @adeneo: Of course SVG elements should have a [`className` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGStylable__className).

Comment: @Bergi - frack, someone finally tested it. They do, and hasClass works just fine!

Comment: @Bergi or maybe not so much -> http://jsfiddle.net/W6pwC/

Comment: **jQuery 2.2.0** fixed this problem - you can see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34698009/3885376 containing some details + a small example that now `hasClass()`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()` work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class attribute for HTML element doesn't have the same meaning in SVG.

```
$("<b></b>").addClass($(this).attr("class")).hasClass("node")
```

Or

```
/(^|\s)node(\s|$)/.test($(this).attr("class"))
```

for SVG elements.

**EDIT** .hasClass seems to work just fine (at least in IE9 and FF) http://jsfiddle.net/X6BPX/1/

So the problem could be any combination of the following: a syntax error, using an outdated browser, using an outdated version of jQuery.

Comment: What else would `class` mean in SVG?

Comment: @Bergi - It's just a regular attribute instead of a special styling attribute like it is in HTML elements with browser specific hooks like className vs class.

Comment: @Bergi - http://jsfiddle.net/TRKF6/  notice how elm.class, elm.className, elm.getAttribute('class'), elm.getAttribute('className') all respond differently than a standard HTML Element. Older versions of jQuery may not account for these differences.

Comment: Nope, only the `className` property yields a different value. Check http://jsfiddle.net/TRKF6/1/ for a comparison. If you get different values for the other properties you should probably update your browser.

Comment: @Bergi - Your right just className is different, and that's enough to break an outdated JavaScript library that expects className to act a specific way; it's also enough to say that SVG and HTML elements are not equivalent with regards to class.

Comment: I'm not sure what the linked (edit) JSFiddle intends to prove, as it's using a div. Here's one with an SVG that fails as the question suggests: http://jsfiddle.net/Mm3TE/

Answer (score 7):

As Bergi pointed out in comments, jQuery silently fails on SVG elements on account of `className` returning an `SVGAnimatedString` object instead of a normal `DOMString`.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mm3TE/6/) for a comparison.

I was tempted to submit a pull request on this, but did a quick project search, and apparently the jQuery project stance on SVG issues is wontfix: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1511

If you're using [`D3`](http://d3js.org/), you could use `d3.select(this).classed('node')`. Note that D3 correctly returns for both HTML elements and SVG elements.

Comment: It would be nice if jQuery's documentation stated this lack of support (or unexpected results). The [hasClass() API doc](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass()/) says _"As of jQuery 1.12/2.2, this method supports XML documents, including SVG"_

Answer (score 4):

This is not the fastest option ever, but it is a possible solution. Instead of using jQuery's `hasClass` you could instead obtain the `class` attribute as a string and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to search through it. There are probably use cases where this will fail, so I wouldn't recommend this except for super simple projects.

Working example:

```
var s = $(this).attr('class');
if( s.indexOf('node')!==-1 ){
    // do something
}
```

Remember: `indexOf` returns `-1` when it can't find anything, not `0`. `0` is returned when the substring starts at index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack for addClass, removeClass, hasClass jquery methods for before jquery 3.x.x versions.

```
$.fn.extend({
    addSVGClass: function (cls) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var classList = $(this).attr('class');
            if (classList) {
                var classListArr = classList.split(" ");
                if (classListArr.indexOf(cls) === -1) {
                    classListArr.push(cls);
                    classList = classListArr.join(" ").trim();
                    $(this).attr('class', classList);
                }
            } else {
                $(this).attr('class', cls);
            }
        });
    },
    removeSVGClass: function (cls) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var classList = $(this).attr('class');
            if (classList) {
                var classListArr = classList.split(" ");
                if (classListArr.indexOf(cls) !== -1) {
                    delete classListArr[classListArr.indexOf(cls)];
                    classList = classListArr.join(" ").trim();
                    $(this).attr('class', classList);
                }
            }

        });
    },
    hasSVGClass: function (cls) {
        var el = this[0];
        var classList = $(el).attr('class');
        if (classList) {
            var classListArr = classList.split(" ");
            if (classListArr.indexOf(cls) !== -1) {
                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

usage :

```
$('.svg-element').addSVGClass('selected');
```

Answer (score -4):

Works. But be sure to close the function

```
$(".node").hover(function(evt){
    console.log($(this).attr("class")); //returns "node"
    console.log($(this).hasClass('node')); //returns false
}, function(){console.log("Done");});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6BPX/

Comment: Thanks Rick, but I did clarify in the comments that the missing parenthesis was a typo. The function I have on my computer is closed.

Comment: @Rick: how is this "works", when `hasClass('node')` returns false?!

Comment: completely useless fiddle - it demonstrates that is works for HTML elements. Nobody was questioning that. The issue at hand is that it does not work with SVG elements. (that is, jQuery .hasClass() doesn't.)

Comment: Here is the corrected Fiddle which shows that .hasClass() doesn't work on inline SVG elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/X6BPX/8/