# change values in standalone svg with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, filter, blur

I am making a blur in Firefox using :"filter: url(blur.svg#blur);" which is in a CSS file, I want to change a value in blur.svg using javascript.

I saw this [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript) and this [Dynamically modifying an SVG filter with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129298/dynamically-modifying-an-svg-filter-with-javascript) but the first creates a object of svg in the html and the second the filter exists in the html which i do not want, I was hoping I can access it without doing that.

Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help.