# Can't access an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, internet-explorer-11

I am having problem modifying an attribute of an HTML element using jQuery `attr` command.  I have a script that inserts an SVG element with a child element that has the attribute `stdDeviation`. You can see that the D letter is **capitalized**.

When I try to get the attribute using

```
$("#myparentdiv feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation"),
```

The attribute can't be retrieved because the attribute is **not found**. I try to set the `stdDeviation` attribute to lowercase in the code, but when I try to access it with lowercase, it shows in Internet Explorer 11 (debugging on this browser), that the attribute with the `D` as uppercase instead of lower case.

When I try to write the attribute, it put a second attribute with a lower case, so I get to have two of those attributes, one with a lowercase D and one with uppercase.

I don't know which to blame, jQuery or IE11 and can't seem to solve this. Any idea?

The Code (after setting the attribute):

```
<div id="some_id_1">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="t3">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0" stddeviation="39" />
       </filter>
    </defs>
     <image filter="url(&quot;#t3&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="350.048px" height="768.75px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/test1.png" />
 </svg>
 </div>
```

Trying to access it from code:

```
  $("#some_id_1 " + "feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation", radius);
```

What it does: sets the attribute as lowercase instead of what I've wrote with uppercase. You can see that it shows twice after the update.

Comment: Would be nice to see your code

Comment: I will add it in a few seconds

Comment: Is `feGaussianBlur` an ID or class? `$("#myparentdiv feGaussianBlur")`

Comment: This might be helpful: [Dynamically Modifying An SVG Filter With Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129298/dynamically-modifying-an-svg-filter-with-javascript)

Comment: I'd blame jquery - even in chrome this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zGtL/1/ doesn't return `feGaussianBlur` element

Comment: It seems that I'm stuck in nowhere's land. Any workaround?

Comment: @showdev I will check it out and report back

Comment: Apparently jquery case folds the attribute names as well as selector ones - that's why the element is not being found (`feGaussianBlur` becomes `fegaussianblur`). As it's of a `wontfix` status I'd rely on modifying it via pure JS.

Comment: @showdev the solution worked. You can reference the other answer as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure if feGaussianBlur is a class, that you select it this way (period in front):

```
$("#myparentdiv .feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation")
```

If it is an ID, select it this way: (# in front)

```
$("#myparentdiv #feGaussianBlur").attr("stdDeviation")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: showdev's solution should fix your problem. Use regular javascript and not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am chekcking it right now. Happy to know that I am not the first to tackle this issue

Comment: If that doesn't work, let me know I will look at another solution.