# Angular animation on a SVG element

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, svg

I would like to animate `ngRepeat` on a SVG element, with Angular 1.2.0rc3, but I can't find the reason why my code doesn't work.

Actually, the following code works perfectly:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100">
    <rect ng-repeat="item in itemsList" width="10" height="50" fill="gold" data-ng-attr-x="{{$index*15}}" class="animation" />
</svg>

<div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList" class="animation">[{{$index}}] {{item}}</div>
</div>
```

```css
.animation.ng-enter,
.animation.ng-leave
{
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2000ms;
}

.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.animation.ng-leave
{
    opacity: 1;
}

.animation.ng-enter,
.animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/sWdJB/)</kbd>

But for some mysterious reason, when I put these lines **in my real project**, the `<rect>` elements aren't animated anymore. The `<div>` elements, however, are still animated. And finally, when I manually add the `.ng-leave` and `.ng-leave-active` classes on an existing element, with Firebug for instance, i can see the `<rect>` progressively disappear, as expected. A pretty nice Heisenbug, right?

Notice that I also use **jQuery** in my project.

Does someone already has encountered a similar issue, or simply has an idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging a long time in the source code of my project, AngularJS and jQuery, it appears that the problem comes from jQuery. Indeed, my example works [without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/sWdJB/) but is broken [with it](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/sWdJB/1/).

Let's go deeper: Angular needs to dynamically add classes to the elements in order to animate them. For that purpose, it uses the `addClass()` method ([see the call in the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ngAnimate/animate.js#L729)). The [jqLite version](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/jqLite.js#L299) of `addClass()` is simple enough to work on SVG elements in modern browser. **That's not the case in the jQuery's one**, as shown by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass).

The solution is either, not to use jQuery at all, to use [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) and his DOM extension, which correct the problem…

```html
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-animate.js"></script>
```

… or simply to use the jqLite version of `addClass()`:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.addClass = function (cssClasses)
    {
        this.each(function ()
        {
            var element = this;
            if (cssClasses && element.setAttribute) {
                var existingClasses = (' ' + (element.getAttribute('class') || '') + ' ')
                                        .replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ");

                $.each(cssClasses.split(' '), function(i, cssClass) {
                  cssClass = cssClass.trim();
                  if (existingClasses.indexOf(' ' + cssClass + ' ') === -1) {
                    existingClasses += cssClass + ' ';
                  }
                });

                element.setAttribute('class', existingClasses.trim());
            }
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Well investigated! Hopefully you'll save someone else a headache in the future with this.