# Using JQuery I am not able to remove class and add class to my SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to use the JQuery click event to remove a class and add a different class but my SVG object is not changing the fill as expected.

```
 $(".seat").click(function (event) {
      var result = $(this).data("seat");
      var state = $(this).data("state");
      $(this).removeClass( "seat" ).addClass( "taken" );
       result = result +" - "+ state;
       $("#statusBox").html(result);

       });
```

My JS fiddle is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cHLS/)

Comment: Your answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `class` does not work the same for SVG tags as it does for standard HTML, at least in respect to jQuery. Rather than treat it as you would a class, you need to treat it like an attribute.

```
$(".seat").on('click',function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $data = $this.data();

    $this.attr('class','taken');

    $("#statusBox").html($data.seat +" - "+ $data.state);
});
```

Since you were removing the only class present and giving it a new class, I simply assigned the attribute of `class` the new value of `taken`. If your actual code is more complex with multiple classnames, you may need to get creative, but the concept remains the same ... replacing that part of the attribute's string value.

I also updated your code to be a bit more efficient, hope thats cool. [Here is the working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3cHLS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `addClass()` or `removeClass()` work with svg. If I remember correctly you'll need to use `.attr()`

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/3cHLS/3/)**

JS:

```
$(".seat").click(function (event) {
       var result = $(this).data("seat");
       var state = $(this).data("state");
       $(this).attr('class', 'taken');
       result = result +" - "+ state;
       $("#statusBox").html(result);                     
});
```