# Shiny Custom Output not Rendering

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

I'm trying to bind a network visualization from D3.js to a custom output in Shiny. For some reason, it seems like my rendering functions are not being called. Here is my code:

rbindings.js

```
var forceNetworkOB = new Shiny.OutputBinding();

forceNetworkOB.find = function(scope) {
  return $(scope).find("svg.rio-force-network");
};

forceNetworkOB.renderValue = function(el, graph) {

  alert('rendering')

  //actual rendering code here...

};

Shiny.outputBindings.register(forceNetworkOB, "jumpy.forceNetworkOB");
```

CustomIO.R

```
renderForceNetwork <- function(expr, env=parent.frame(), quoted=FALSE) {

  func <- exprToFunction(expr, env, quoted)

  function() {

    # Never called
    browser()

    graph <- func()

    list(nodes = graph$nodes,
         links = graph$edges
    )
  }
}

forceNetwork <- function(id, width = '400px', height = '400px') {

  tag('svg', list(id = id, class = 'rio-force-network', width = width, height = height))

}
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
source('customIO.R')

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$script(src = 'js/d3.min.js'),
  tags$script(src = 'js/rbindings.js'),

  titlePanel('Network Visualization'),

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('D3.js Force Layout',
      forceNetwork('vis.force', width = '800px', height = '800px'),
    )
  )

))
```

and server.R

```
library(shiny)

source('cytoscape.R')
source('customIO.R')

shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {


  # Load the network
  network <- networkFromCytoscape('network.cyjs')

  output$vis.force <- renderForceNetwork({

    # Never called
    print('rendering')
    browser()

    list(
      nodes = data.frame(name = network$nodes.data$Label_for_display, group = rep(1, nrow(network$nodes.data))),
      edges = data.frame(from = network$edges[,1], to = network$edges[,2])
    )

  })

})
```

As you can see from the comments, the browser() lines in my R rendering functions are never called, as well as the alert() in the js rendering function. With some js debugging I can see that my custom binding is correctly giving the svg element to render to as well as its id. This might be something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, although the code seems all legitimate, you really have to dig into the source code of Shiny to find the culprit.

When Shiny initializes, it calls `initShiny()`, which then calls `bindOutputs`. 
Now, here is what the `bindOutputs` function looks like:

```
function bindOutputs(scope) {

  if (scope === undefined)
    scope = document;

  scope = $(scope);

  var bindings = outputBindings.getBindings();

  for (var i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
    var binding = bindings[i].binding;
    var matches = binding.find(scope) || [];
    for (var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
      var el = matches[j];
      var id = binding.getId(el);

      // Check if ID is falsy
      if (!id)
        continue;

      var bindingAdapter = new OutputBindingAdapter(el, binding);
      shinyapp.bindOutput(id, bindingAdapter);
      $(el).data('shiny-output-binding', bindingAdapter);
      $(el).addClass('shiny-bound-output'); // <- oops!
    }
  }

  // Send later in case DOM layout isn't final yet.
  setTimeout(sendImageSize, 0);
  setTimeout(sendOutputHiddenState, 0);
}
```

The line I marked with `<- oops` is what causes all the problem. 
This really isn't a bug of Shiny *per se*: this line of code relies on `jQuery` to add a class to `el`, which is the `svg` DOM element that you've created with `forceNetwork()` function.

The class `shiny-bound-output` is important for the *actual* binding to work.

**The problem is that `$.addClass` doesn't work for `<svg>`.**
For a good reference, [see this article](http://toddmotto.com/hacking-svg-traversing-with-ease-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass-functions/) or [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass).

So, as a result, your `<svg>` element lacks the required `shiny-bound-output` class that would make your custom `OutputBinding` to function correctly.

---

#### Solution:

**Don't use `<svg>` as the container of your output**. Use a `<div>` instead.
It means, you should change your `forceNetwork` function to:

```
forceNetwork <- function(id, width = '400px', height = '400px') {    
  tag('div', list(id = id, class = 'rio-force-network', width = width, height = height))
}
```

You can easily append a `<svg>` using `d3.select(...).append('svg')` and set the width and height there.

(Remember to modify your `find()` function in `rbindings.js` as well).

---

#### The final word

If you somehow add `d3.select(...).append('svg')` to your javascript code, remember to `clear()` the `<div>` container in the output binding's `renderValue()` function before the actual d3 drawing. Otherwise every time `renderForceNetwork` is called, it will add a new `<svg>` element to your `<div>` container.

Comment: This is the right answer! Thanks, I never would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: I've learnt this strange behavior today thanks to your question. :)