# Not able to get the class to be toggled/added through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass, toggleclass

Please consider my apologies for this lengthy question.

**Question:** Not able to get the class to toggled/added through jquery.

**Scenario:**
I have drawn a random shape using path element of svg in html. Using the css i can get the marching ants effect for the shape. I have used the below css code to do that.

```
.content {
  stroke-dasharray: 10 5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 15s linear infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}
```

This gives a marching ants effect in one direction. If you want in another direction you have to reverse the from and to in @-webkit-keyframes.

**What I want to do?**
I want to change the direction of the marching ants depending on the position of the cursor.

**What I have done now?**
I have defined separate animation rules for each direction "marching" effect. here it is:

```
.content1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 10 5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 15s linear infinite;
}

.content2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 10 5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: dash_reverse 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash_reverse {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Through Javascript I am trying to determine the position of cursor and change the class of the element. Here is Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var content = $("#content");
    var left  = content.offset().left;
    var pageX = event.pageX;

    if (pageX<left) {
        $("#content").addClass("content1");
        $("#content").removeClass("content2");
        }
    else {
        $("#content").addClass("content2");
        $("#content").removeClass("content1");
        }
  });
});
```

but i am not getting the animation effect when i execute the javascript code. I have tried to use the toggleClass() method but no results.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nua2dszc/) is the JSfiddle link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7oca4yt/) demonstrates the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot 'raina77ow'. that is the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no class attribute found in html.

```
if (pageX<left) {
    $("#content").attr("class","content1");
    }
else {
    $("#content").attr("class","content2");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **jQuery does not support classes of SVG elements**, thats why you have to use **.attr()** method instead of  .addClass() .removeClass().

Nice explanations and examples in old ticket: [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)