# How to rotate an svg image based on origin using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have the following code to create an SVG image of a needle( something like the needle in a speedometer).

```
<circle class="needle-center" cx="200" cy="200" r="5"></circle>
<path class="needle" d="M 195 198 L 200 100 L 205 202  "></path>
<button id="test">Click Here</button>
```

On clicking the button i'm trying to rotate the svg image using Jquery function.

```
  $("#test").click(function () {
        $('.needle').css(" transform-origin", "bottom");
        $('.needle').attr("transform", "rotate(45)");
        });
```

Instead of rotating it is just randomly moving away. How can i fix this? Is there a better way to animate svg? (i'm new to SVG)

Before clicking:
[image]

After clicking:
[image]

Comment: Using jQuery to manipulate svgs will often be quite a pain. For an explanation check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29805796/4235784) and the links therein which I posted recently to a similar question. Doing simple manipulations like the ones you posted could instead be done by means of pure JavaScript without the need for any framework.

Comment: Can you specify the center of rotation by setting the `cx` and `cy` in `rotate(<rotate-angle> [<cx> <cy>])`?

Comment: In css i added the following for that particular class it was rotating.
               transform: rotate(30deg);
                transform-origin: 100% 100%;
But when i tried doing the same through Jquery it is not working:
                 $('.needleset').css("transform", "rotate(30deg)");
                $('.needleset').css(" transform-origin", "100% 100%");