# In D3, how can I receive current X,Y coordinates of an element while a transition is running?

Tags: d3.js, svg

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184339/1437023), how can I get a live stream of the circle's X & Y coordinates while the transition is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to take control of the transition and write a custom `tween` function.  This way you control each animation step.  Here's some runnable code replacing the attrTween magic in your example with a custom tween.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("cx", Math.random() * 200)
    .attr("cy", Math.random() * 200)
    .attr("r", 10 + "px");
    
myTransf();

function myTransf() {
    circle.transition()
     .duration(500)
      .each("end", function () {
          myTransf();
      })
      .tween("move", function() {
        var self = d3.select(this),
            x = d3.interpolate(+self.attr('cx'), Math.random() * 200),
            y = d3.interpolate(+self.attr('cy'), Math.random() * 200);
        return function(t) {
          var cx = x(t),
              cy = y(t);
          self.attr("cx", cx);
          self.attr("cy", cy);
        };
      });
}
```

```css
svg {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I came up with an [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39551543/4235784) to your approach and, because I like your contributions, I'd really appreciate you having a look into it.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I utilized the tween function, but I'll have to look into MutationObserver further now for future uses.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the standard [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface to listen for changes to the DOM. The `MutationObserver` constructor is provided a callback which will be called with an array of [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord)s containing detailed information about the changes which occured. After creating an observer instance you can register it to changes to a particular node, e.g. your circle, and filter the attribute changes you are interested in, say `cx` and `cy`, by providing this configuration to the call to [`.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#observe()) which will start the listener.

```
// Create a new MutationObserver.
// This one just logs changes to attributes.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(m) {
    console.log(
      m.attributeName + 
      " -- old:" + m.oldValue +
      ", new: " + m.target.getAttribute(m.attributeName));
  });
});

// Start observing the circle node and listen for changes to attributes cx and cy
// while recording old values.
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  attributeFilter: ["cx","cy"]
};

observer.observe(circle.node(), config);
```

Given the JSFiddle you linked to, a working example might look like this:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var circle = svg.append("circle")
 .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("cx", Math.random() * 200)
    .attr("cy", Math.random() * 200)
    .attr("r", 10 + "px")
    .transition().each("end", function () {
      myTransf();
  });

var d = d3.select("div");
function myTransf() {
    d3.select("#circ").transition().duration(500)
        .attr("cx", Math.random() * 200) // change this to random 2px 
     .attr("cy", Math.random() * 200) // change this to random 2px
        .each("end", function () {
        myTransf();
    });
}

// Create a new MutationObserver.
// This one just logs changes to attributes.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(m) {
    console.log(
      m.attributeName + 
      " -- old:" + m.oldValue +
      ", new: " + m.target.getAttribute(m.attributeName));
  });
});

// Start observing the circle node and listen for changes to attributes cx and cy
// while recording old values.
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  attributeFilter: ["cx","cy"]
};

observer.observe(circle.node(), config);

// Stop observing once you are done
setTimeout(function() {
  observer.disconnect();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

If you need to [support IE <11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility), though, you are out of luck and need to resort to some other solution like [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39550687/4235784) proposed by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark).

Comment: That's a very cool approach.  It allows you to leverage the built-in magic of `d3`s transition will still hooking each iteration.  +1