# How replace content (innerSVG?) from string SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, snap.svg

I can't get the children from the svg fragment pre-entered in the string.
Need return content `<g>` element from source string;
Example:
has dom:

```
<svg>
   <g class="parent"> <rect ... /> </g>
<svg>
```

```
let strNewContent = '<g class="draggable-group" data-id-device="Light-X[room-1549613406671][0]">   <rect height="75" width="184" x="8" y="0" fill="#DDD" rx="6" ry="6" />  </g>'; // created svg string using handlebars.js
// need replace old content in new content
// need extrude `<rect ... /> & etc...` from string and put (innerSVG) 

$('.parent').html($(strNewContent).html()) // I understand it won't work. (It's just to understand what I mean.)

d3.select(svgElem).html(d3.select(svgElem).html()); // костыль для обновления svg документа
```

*ps:Thank you for your patience and understanding for my English*

need extrude `<rect ... /> & etc...` from string and put (innerSVG)

I understand that this can be done in 2 ways (as I can see): by a regular expression, cut the content  or convert it to a fragment and try to squeeze out the content and add it to a new element as content (helped by **@altocumulus**). But I really already tried, many times to convert to a fragment and to squeeze out contents, nothing turns out (only now came to the decision, with a regular expression)(now I will experiment).

*ps: What's best to correct (title) the issue for everyone to deal with this problem to solve it?*

Comment: Doesn't `d3.select(".parent").html(strNewContent).select("rect");` do what you want? See https://jsfiddle.net/vbjunfd8/1/

Comment: Yes, Your code is working. I wrote a question last night and got a little typoed (understated). I can answer it as true. (I here is think create a new question or edit this a bit?)

Comment: @altocumulus, I apologize for wasting Your time by my mistake.

Comment: All-same decided to wrap in svg and to issue `d3.select ('.parent').html ($(\`<svg>${strNewContent}</svg>\`).find('.draggable-group').html() );`

Comment: Don't use jQuery to manipulate an SVG's DOM as it was designed for the HTML namespace and does not work well with SVG's namespace. Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805796/4235784) to [*"Style a d3 element with jQuery and CSS"*](/q/29805098) for more details. Why are you mixing in jQuery in the first place? You said that my first suggested solution did work, right? I am afraid, I don't really understand what you are after.