# Change classes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I'm new to jQuery and I got a problem related to adding and removing classes to an element with a certain ID. This is what I want to do (and also it works just fine, but I want to know the jQuery-solution):

```
$('#blub').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('myelement').classList.toggle("myclass");
});
```

This is what I did:

```
$('#blub').click(function() {
    $('#myelement').toggleClass('myclass');
});
```

It's a fairly stupid question, probably, but I just can't find the mistake.

edit: I have added a snippet, as the syntax itself seems to be alright. Thanks your help so far :)

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#blub').click(function() {
    $('#myelement').toggleClass('myclass');
  });
 
});
```

```css
#myelement {
  fill: red;  
}

.myclass {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="blub" style="border:none; background: none; width:300px; height:100px;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect id="myelement" class="myclass" width="300" height="100" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: the second one is the jquery solution. It should be working

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted? It would appear to be the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it just doesn't work. I don't know why, so I have added a snippet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. One is css, the id selector overrides the styles.

   Solution:

   ```
   #myelement {
    fill: red;  
   }

   #myelement.myclass {
     fill: blue;
   }
   ```
2. There is issue with jquery itself while dealing with svg elements [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

   Solution:

   ```
   $('#blub').click(function() {
     $('#myelement')[0].classList.toggle('myclass')
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct see the below example.

```js
$('#blub').click(function() {
  $('#myelement').toggleClass('myclass');
});
```

```css
#myelement {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
#myelement.myclass {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="blub">Click</button>

<div id="myelement">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way;

```
 $('#blub').click(function() {
   if($('#myelement').hasClass('myClass'))
      $('#myelement').removeClass('myclass');
   else
      $('#myelement').addClass('myclass');
 });
```