# Geography quiz, highlighting the right answer

Tags: jquery, highlight, area, imagemap, geography

I'm doing a geography quiz with maps and image maps. The website shows country names and users have to choose the right location on the map.

When users click on an area a message appears telling them if the answer is right or not. I managed to do that, but I don't know how to highlight the answer, I mean, if the text is france, to highlight France (that area) when clicking on the "show me" button, or in any area.

Any thoughts?

I know how to highlight the clicked area, but nothing more.

This is the code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.item').hide();
  $('.current').show(); 
  $('.sorry').hide();
  $('.continuar').attr("disabled", true);

  $('.mapping').click(function() {

  if ($(this).attr('id') == $('.current').attr('id')){

      alert("Muy bien");
      $('.continuar').attr("disabled", false);  

     } else {

        $('.sorry').show();
        alert("sorry!");
 } // telling the users if they got the correct answer
 });



 $('img[usemap]').maphilight();  // hilighting areas when mouseover

 $('li').draggable({containment: 'document', revert: true,

  start: function () {
  contents = $(this).text();    
  }
  });

  $('#list').droppable({ hoverClass:'border', accept: '.item',
  drop: function(){
  $('#list').append(contents + '<br/ >');
   }
   });  // trying to drag text on an area, not working so far, I don't even know if that's possible

   $(".continuar").click(function(){
            $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');
            $('.continuar').attr("disabled", true);
            }); 

    $(".muestrame").click(function(){
            $('.current').attr('id') = $('.current').attr('id').data('maphilight') || {};
            data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
            $('.current').attr('id').data('maphilight',   data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
            }); 

  $('.mapping').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    }); // hilighting the clicked area


 });
```

Comment: your best bet is to use `svg` or `canvas` rather than `img`

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Not, yet. Meanwhile I´m using links instead. I have a list with the countries and when someone is clicked, the correct area hilights. But I'll keep trying.

Comment: Have you tried the solution below, why didn't it work?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to use svg or canvas, I'm really a newbie and I don't have much time now, so I'm working with the things I know, and for now I´ll do it with links. But I'll take a look at it. There are so many things to learn... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

## SVG Solution

I would use SVG basically because I'm not familiar with canvas. The cool thing about SVG is that it works like regular HTML so CSS (and often even jQuery) works beautifully on it.

### Basic Usage

For example, to style paths that are **hovered** over:

```
path:hover {
  fill: #8af;
}
```

Or, using jQuery you can **highlight elements by id** (in your case, the one that is the correct answer):

```
$("#NewSouthWales").css("fill", "#038");
```

Which would be the same as using CSS but with jQuery you could highlight the element after an event (such as submitting an answer).

### A Caveat and a Solution

You can also highlight based on CSS selectors using jQuery and dynamically add/remove classes (or anything CSS selectors can target). The only problem is that `addClass` and its associated functions [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass).

```
$("path").on("click", function(){
  $(".selected").attr("class", "");
  $(this).attr("class", "selected");
});
```

If found a simple map of Australia and applied the above principles to it.

**Try out the snippet to see it all in action.**

```js
var highlightedId;
$(document).on("input", "#highlighter", function(){
  $( "#" + highlightedId ).removeAttr( 'style' );
  highlightedId = $(this).val();
  $( "#" + highlightedId ).css("fill", "#038");
})

/*$(document).on("click", "path", function(){
  $(".selected").attr("class", "");
  $(this).attr("class", "selected");
});*/
```

```css
path:hover {
  fill: #8af;
}
path.selected {
  fill: #8fa;
}
div {
  margin: 2em;
}
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="200" height="186" id="svg2">
  <defs id="defs5" />
  <g fill="#d3d3d3" stroke="black">
    <path id="NewSouthWales" d="M 199.1875,104.4375 C 198.83653,104.43081 198.34998,104.46425 198.0625,104.4375 C 197.31177,104.36764 196.77298,104.23444 196.34375,104.09375 C 195.48529,103.81238 195.10212,103.46104 194.5625,103.46875 C 193.71456,103.48021 193.37252,103.7504 193.1875,104 C 193.00248,104.2496 192.98169,104.49188 192.78125,104.46875 C 192.3825,104.42274 192.14493,104.58987 191.96875,104.875 C 191.79257,105.16013 191.69504,105.5619 191.5625,105.96875 C 191.42996,106.3756 191.26782,106.80584 191,107.125 C 190.73218,107.44416 190.33204,107.66545 189.75,107.6875 C 189.1067,107.71125 188.63102,107.50296 188.21875,107.1875 C 187.80648,106.87204 187.4631,106.42838 187.15625,106 C 186.8494,105.57162 186.57703,105.15876 186.25,104.84375 C 185.92297,104.52874 185.53532,104.3191 185.0625,104.34375 C 183.87838,104.40547 183.48532,104.16837 183.0625,103.90625 C 182.63968,103.64413 182.19488,103.375 181,103.375 C 180.39544,103.375 180.03006,103.50748 179.75,103.71875 C 179.46994,103.93002 179.28524,104.21381 179.0625,104.5 C 178.83976,104.78619 178.58886,105.05649 178.15625,105.28125 C 177.72364,105.50601 177.09715,105.69177 176.1875,105.71875 C 175.03771,105.75229 174.35678,105.40622 173.75,105.0625 C 173.14322,104.71878 172.61423,104.35834 171.8125,104.28125 C 162.86678,103.42108 141.32486,102.26983 138.625,102.125 L 137.03125,129.53125 C 137.54917,129.75192 138.56431,129.81254 139.625,129.96875 C 140.18125,130.05067 140.7364,130.16482 141.21875,130.34375 C 141.7011,130.52268 142.08885,130.77013 142.34375,131.125 C 142.64472,131.544 142.75321,132.43548 142.90625,133.15625 C 142.98277,133.51663 143.07146,133.83373 143.21875,134.03125 C 143.36604,134.22877 143.55385,134.31173 143.84375,134.1875 C 144.58118,133.87151 145.20772,133.73096 145.71875,133.75 C 146.22978,133.76904 146.62195,133.9476 146.90625,134.21875 C 147.19055,134.4899 147.38025,134.84091 147.4375,135.28125 C 147.49475,135.72159 147.42012,136.25463 147.25,136.78125 C 147.14001,137.12174 148.23355,138.26366 149.5625,139.46875 C 150.89145,140.67384 152.47624,141.93906 153.34375,142.4375 C 153.64326,142.60959 153.85198,142.60307 154.03125,142.53125 C 154.21052,142.45943 154.35851,142.30018 154.46875,142.125 C 154.68924,141.77463 154.81085,141.35808 155.0625,141.4375 C 155.63899,141.61945 156.09667,141.52701 156.46875,141.5 C 156.84083,141.47299 157.13028,141.52068 157.40625,141.96875 C 157.64888,142.36269 157.88431,142.56006 158.125,142.65625 C 158.36569,142.75244 158.61509,142.75307 158.84375,142.71875 C 159.07241,142.68443 159.29347,142.6226 159.5,142.625 C 159.70653,142.6274 159.88819,142.69988 160.0625,142.90625 C 160.26498,143.14597 160.64031,143.3045 161.0625,143.40625 C 161.48469,143.508 161.95643,143.5547 162.3125,143.5625 C 163.99682,143.59939 165.36951,143.29586 166.34375,143.34375 C 166.83087,143.36769 167.22712,143.47707 167.5,143.75 C 167.77288,144.02293 167.9346,144.47017 167.96875,145.15625 C 168.023,146.24621 168.41182,147.191 169.03125,148.03125 C 169.65068,148.8715 170.48262,149.60479 171.40625,150.28125 C 172.45463,151.04908 173.48117,151.69999 174.5625,152.375 C 174.8182,151.87258 175.08006,151.42329 175.375,150.8125 C 176.02844,149.4593 178.06166,145.28606 179.875,141.53125 C 181.68833,137.77643 184.94923,131.98884 187.9375,129.5 C 191.29853,126.7007 194.17919,122.69785 196.125,116.1875 C 197.73949,110.78569 198.72715,108.50415 199.1875,104.4375 z M 173.15625,139.5 C 173.49282,139.48654 173.83893,139.54187 174.15625,139.6875 C 174.42841,139.81241 174.5172,139.99038 174.5,140.1875 C 174.4828,140.38462 174.34449,140.60476 174.1875,140.84375 C 173.87351,141.32172 173.44461,141.8492 173.46875,142.3125 C 173.41231,142.56664 173.14933,143.11767 172.78125,143.1875 C 172.59721,143.22241 172.37325,143.13855 172.15625,142.84375 C 171.93925,142.54895 171.71999,142.03235 171.5,141.21875 C 171.3657,140.72206 171.52233,140.30047 171.84375,140 C 172.16517,139.69953 172.6514,139.5202 173.15625,139.5 z "
    />
    <path id="ACT" d="M 173.15625,139.5 C 173.49282,139.48654 173.83893,139.54187 174.15625,139.6875 C 174.42841,139.81241 174.5172,139.99038 174.5,140.1875 C 174.4828,140.38462 174.34449,140.60476 174.1875,140.84375 C 173.87351,141.32172 173.44461,141.8492 173.46875,142.3125 C 173.41231,142.56664 173.14933,143.11767 172.78125,143.1875 C 172.59721,143.22241 172.37325,143.13855 172.15625,142.84375 C 171.93925,142.54895 171.71999,142.03235 171.5,141.21875 C 171.3657,140.72206 171.52233,140.30047 171.84375,140 C 172.16517,139.69953 172.6514,139.5202 173.15625,139.5 z "
    />
    <path id="WA" d="M 81.34375,116.59375 L 80.09375,84.65625 L 80.09375,84.65625 L 77.6875,23.1875 C 77.650137,23.187993 77.632299,23.187635 77.59375,23.1875 C 73.296472,23.069469 67.140263,13.184428 63.3125,18.75 C 59.504317,24.287099 57.095867,17.962153 56.15625,26.0625 C 56.024926,27.194634 54.772933,26.53125 53.875,26.53125 C 52.667486,26.53125 51.386077,27.50511 53.21875,29.28125 C 54.599569,30.619475 53.239124,32.065249 51.90625,31.75 C 49.878126,31.270312 47.919146,32.362582 48.25,32.9375 C 50.40019,36.673835 51.04898,36.105091 49.375,37.21875 C 47.938402,38.174485 49.287386,41.02806 45.59375,32.5 C 45.131405,31.432512 40.756698,37.302049 41.28125,39.3125 C 41.68541,40.861521 42.817966,43.46875 42.375,43.46875 C 41.932034,43.468749 39.726622,43.420331 39.1875,46.59375 C 38.488799,50.70649 32.766607,54.375 29.40625,54.375 C 28.277331,54.375 27.109166,54.772906 26.8125,55.25 C 26.515834,55.727093 23.246293,57.681105 19.5625,59.21875 C 15.878706,60.756394 11.260809,61.718908 10.59375,63.6875 C 10.001486,65.435361 7.267423,66.014934 5.84375,67.625 C 3.939475,69.778592 3.2900965,72.476945 2.90625,69.71875 C 1.8264064,61.959352 1.1038508,71.150969 0.40625,73.40625 C -0.068993191,74.942671 2.0117668,77.109056 2,77.6875 C 1.9335602,80.953613 -1.8794139,83.268691 3.90625,87.71875 C 5.8392429,89.205517 7.8543327,92.775264 4.53125,95.09375 C 1.9091635,96.92316 7.8253797,99.121714 7.625,102.03125 C 7.5013423,103.82677 12.281122,107.60461 12.78125,108.8125 C 13.690418,111.00828 13.850005,115.86365 16.34375,118.25 C 18.641646,120.44893 19.548817,131.26856 18.6875,131.25 C 15.825447,131.18833 15.444226,137.15372 18.9375,136.25 C 20.876685,135.74833 21.349234,137.98662 22.28125,138.78125 C 24.745238,140.88202 33.342431,138.55156 34.75,135.9375 C 35.311816,134.89413 36.460954,134.46875 37.0625,134.46875 C 38.499967,134.46875 38.432385,132.98307 39,132.15625 C 39.277705,131.75173 40.935238,131.80781 42.65625,131.40625 C 44.315193,131.01916 46.042144,129.94093 46.625,130 C 47.768966,130.11593 48.697011,131.35085 49.84375,131.40625 C 50.499486,131.43794 54.192038,129.88418 55.46875,129.75 C 57.433679,129.54348 58.079857,127.08227 58.5,126 C 59.317407,123.89439 60.501,123.8897 62.84375,123.28125 C 65.949054,122.47477 65.851995,118.89374 72.25,119.875 C 74.419133,120.20768 77.364827,118.01936 78.6875,117.21875 C 79.194641,116.91178 80.186363,116.74344 81.34375,116.59375 z "
    />
    <path id="VIC" d="M 174.5625,152.375 C 173.48117,151.69999 172.45463,151.04908 171.40625,150.28125 C 170.48262,149.60479 169.65068,148.8715 169.03125,148.03125 C 168.41182,147.191 168.023,146.24621 167.96875,145.15625 C 167.9346,144.47017 167.77288,144.02293 167.5,143.75 C 167.22712,143.47707 166.83087,143.36769 166.34375,143.34375 C 165.36951,143.29586 163.99682,143.59939 162.3125,143.5625 C 161.95643,143.5547 161.48469,143.508 161.0625,143.40625 C 160.64031,143.3045 160.26498,143.14597 160.0625,142.90625 C 159.88819,142.69988 159.70653,142.6274 159.5,142.625 C 159.29347,142.6226 159.07241,142.68443 158.84375,142.71875 C 158.61509,142.75307 158.36569,142.75244 158.125,142.65625 C 157.88431,142.56006 157.64888,142.36269 157.40625,141.96875 C 157.13028,141.52068 156.84083,141.47299 156.46875,141.5 C 156.09667,141.52701 155.63899,141.61945 155.0625,141.4375 C 154.81085,141.35808 154.68924,141.77463 154.46875,142.125 C 154.35851,142.30018 154.21052,142.45943 154.03125,142.53125 C 153.85198,142.60307 153.64326,142.60959 153.34375,142.4375 C 152.47624,141.93906 150.89145,140.67384 149.5625,139.46875 C 148.23355,138.26366 147.14001,137.12174 147.25,136.78125 C 147.42012,136.25463 147.49475,135.72159 147.4375,135.28125 C 147.38025,134.84091 147.19055,134.4899 146.90625,134.21875 C 146.62195,133.9476 146.22978,133.76904 145.71875,133.75 C 145.20772,133.73096 144.58118,133.87151 143.84375,134.1875 C 143.55385,134.31173 143.36604,134.22877 143.21875,134.03125 C 143.07146,133.83373 142.98277,133.51663 142.90625,133.15625 C 142.75321,132.43548 142.64472,131.544 142.34375,131.125 C 142.08885,130.77013 141.7011,130.52268 141.21875,130.34375 C 140.7364,130.16482 140.18125,130.05067 139.625,129.96875 C 138.56431,129.81254 137.54917,129.75192 137.03125,129.53125 L 135.6875,152.25 C 136.02406,152.53882 136.25001,152.9014 136.25,153.21875 C 136.25,153.79972 137.27732,154.91695 139.09375,153.53125 C 139.87034,152.93881 141.27596,153.94319 143.3125,154.9375 C 146.39636,156.44315 147.36313,156.53541 149.03125,155.5 C 150.69119,154.46966 151.47218,154.5549 153.71875,155.90625 C 157.41953,160.03161 160.84932,158.56932 162.90625,156 C 163.93159,154.71924 167.35834,153.43344 169.78125,153.78125 C 173.16206,154.26658 174.01051,153.45957 174.5625,152.375 z "
    />
    <path id="QLD" d="M 153.09375,0.625 C 151.98009,0.71116902 149.60324,2.737831 149.625,5.65625 C 149.6381,7.4507695 148.04217,8.4921947 148.1875,10.3125 C 148.42656,13.306863 146.97179,12.749563 147.28125,14.25 C 147.87829,17.144708 146.09237,16.19749 145.9375,18.03125 C 145.83105,19.29176 146.42076,19.454842 146.53125,20.8125 C 147.04031,27.129232 143.78051,36.631373 139.1875,38.15625 C 138.36522,38.429246 137.05134,39.309116 134.875,37.5625 C 133.23989,36.250227 132.23052,34.164092 130.53125,33.59375 C 129.14152,33.127311 127.53339,32.273086 127.25,31.875 C 127.20142,31.806757 126.75759,31.5756 126.6875,31.5 L 124.625,85.25 L 139.625,85.46875 L 138.625,102.125 C 141.32486,102.26983 162.86678,103.42108 171.8125,104.28125 C 172.61423,104.35834 173.14322,104.71878 173.75,105.0625 C 174.35678,105.40622 175.03771,105.75229 176.1875,105.71875 C 177.09715,105.69177 177.72364,105.50601 178.15625,105.28125 C 178.58886,105.05649 178.83976,104.78619 179.0625,104.5 C 179.28524,104.21381 179.46994,103.93002 179.75,103.71875 C 180.03006,103.50748 180.39544,103.375 181,103.375 C 182.19488,103.375 182.63968,103.64413 183.0625,103.90625 C 183.48532,104.16837 183.87838,104.40547 185.0625,104.34375 C 185.53532,104.3191 185.92297,104.52874 186.25,104.84375 C 186.57703,105.15876 186.8494,105.57162 187.15625,106 C 187.4631,106.42838 187.80648,106.87204 188.21875,107.1875 C 188.63102,107.50296 189.1067,107.71125 189.75,107.6875 C 190.33204,107.66545 190.73218,107.44416 191,107.125 C 191.26782,106.80584 191.42996,106.3756 191.5625,105.96875 C 191.69504,105.5619 191.79257,105.16013 191.96875,104.875 C 192.14493,104.58987 192.3825,104.42274 192.78125,104.46875 C 192.98169,104.49188 193.00248,104.2496 193.1875,104 C 193.37252,103.7504 193.71456,103.48021 194.5625,103.46875 C 195.10212,103.46104 195.48529,103.81238 196.34375,104.09375 C 196.77298,104.23444 197.31177,104.36764 198.0625,104.4375 C 198.34998,104.46425 198.83653,104.43081 199.1875,104.4375 C 199.39112,102.6388 199.5,100.57291 199.5,97.59375 C 199.5,89.464417 199.40034,87.542632 198.25,86.59375 C 197.4331,85.919913 196.12707,84.93271 196.28125,83.25 C 196.34755,82.52622 195.31451,79.819883 193.125,78.5625 C 189.4512,76.452713 190.60429,74.281967 190.78125,73.21875 C 191.13615,71.086368 188.01975,67.843751 186.59375,67.84375 C 185.85865,67.843749 184.19338,72.582496 184.21875,64.65625 C 184.22343,63.179926 183.85474,62.198208 183.40625,61.875 C 182.53059,61.243945 182.08891,60.760039 182.125,60.21875 C 182.17114,59.526497 183.38418,58.797241 183.375,58.15625 C 183.35845,57.00133 181.29865,56.929958 180,55.78125 C 174.50908,50.924316 166.90096,49.044563 170.21875,45.78125 C 170.70298,45.304902 168.73509,44.625824 168.3125,43.5 C 168.01601,42.710159 171.84482,42.164183 167.90625,37.5 C 165.62099,34.793721 166.6539,26.979107 166.46875,26.125 C 166.04313,24.161608 163.78055,21.459727 162.53125,21.5 C 160.67178,21.559943 160.88599,22.948951 159.28125,22.625 C 158.09652,22.38584 157.78485,17.34652 157.46875,12.59375 C 157.49838,10.920962 155.83139,10.500918 156.09375,9.5 C 156.73882,7.0390959 154.92948,7.2579828 154.9375,6.5625 C 154.99003,2.0101845 154.72967,0.49842142 153.09375,0.625 z "
    />
    <path id="TAS" d="M 153.48868,183.29975 C 152.73743,182.40088 152.12645,180.1161 152.39992,176.82793 C 152.52943,175.27073 151.27114,174.15429 150.64074,172.97142 C 148.42197,168.80816 151.12927,167.02226 155.07525,169.76931 C 156.74221,170.92978 158.36558,170.95897 161.5036,170.53146 C 164.08932,170.17921 166.31008,170.26332 166.46323,170.97325 C 166.90276,173.01065 165.2328,171.45879 165.41307,175.07528 C 165.47143,176.24593 164.43423,177.77062 164.43775,178.60277 C 164.44401,180.12997 163.34639,180.8467 163.42191,181.6092 C 163.54702,182.87243 162.54823,184.16251 162.20631,184.16251 C 161.24646,184.16251 161.61718,180.9159 159.41272,184.1599 C 158.01826,186.21194 155.174,185.31623 153.48868,183.29975 z "
    />
    <g id="NT">
      <path id="NT-mainland" d="M 77.6875,23.1875 L 80.09375,84.65625 L 124.625,85.25 L 126.6875,31.5 C 126.34872,31.1346 126.02985,30.798945 123.96875,29.6875 C 122.84504,29.081537 110.41237,22.506512 113.4375,20.8125 C 117.49033,18.542997 115.39667,13.994132 117.375,13.3125 C 119.14675,12.702043 122.48408,8.7074617 121.625,7.28125 C 120.27165,6.3016183 118.39536,6.26625 117.71875,7.25 C 117.2877,7.876718 116.32472,7.7911127 115.9375,7.40625 C 115.76772,7.237504 114.92082,6.3159978 114.21875,6.15625 C 113.31958,5.9516578 112.43937,7.4458851 111.1875,6.4375 C 109.4475,5.035927 106.39149,6.603752 101.71875,3.6875 C 96.096913,0.17891536 94.218295,1.161452 95.53125,4.59375 C 96.638347,7.4879052 96.015955,7.7167742 92.15625,7.59375 C 87.669121,7.4507274 86.859536,7.2576632 84.40625,10.34375 C 82.53109,12.351574 83.260056,13.838232 83.0625,14.03125 C 78.306268,18.678257 82.115635,23.12911 77.6875,23.1875 z "
      />
      <path id="Groote-Eyland" d="M 122.16794,15.819607 C 121.95745,15.311193 119.81055,15.787198 119.13138,15.833157 C 118.3545,15.885729 117.86162,17.060638 118.05744,18.036737 C 118.3428,19.459183 120.1872,19.834585 120.41009,18.920037 C 120.60502,18.120236 120.83478,17.800713 121.22343,17.304492 C 121.34585,17.121172 122.31087,16.164849 122.16794,15.819607 z "
      />
      <path id="Melville-Island" d="M 91.533285,1.4725605 C 91.261672,0.26024852 89.113331,2.7579 87.493323,1.8509936 C 87.164378,1.6668453 85.508297,0.96600698 84.468782,2.5627617 C 83.756802,3.6564035 86.206623,5.5438684 88.022838,5.5499127 C 89.626637,5.5550324 89.920511,4.665705 90.18996,4.4508123 C 90.428744,4.2603753 92.155402,4.249309 91.533285,1.4725605 z "
      />
    </g>
    <g id="SA">
      <path id="SA-mainland" d="M 135.6875,152.25 L 137.03125,129.53125 C 137.03125,129.53125 137.03125,129.53125 137.03125,129.53125 L 138.625,102.125 C 138.625,102.125 138.625,102.125 138.625,102.125 L 139.625,85.46875 L 124.625,85.25 L 124.625,85.25 L 80.09375,84.65625 L 81.34375,116.59375 C 82.719716,116.41579 84.362272,116.27201 86.15625,116.0625 C 89.377613,115.6863 90.103338,113.2133 93.78125,116.0625 C 95.725608,117.56875 97.049318,117.30049 99.5,117.84375 C 101.21219,118.22331 105.13075,119.69202 105.875,120.65625 C 106.68451,121.70505 104.42413,121.52647 104.28125,122.53125 C 104.098,123.81992 105.47121,123.72448 106.53125,124 C 107.79709,124.32901 110.14299,126.13445 110.09375,129.03125 C 110.01314,133.77317 111.79843,134.96082 113.71875,133.78125 C 114.2142,133.4769 113.69579,131.49205 114.3125,130.75 C 114.74738,130.22674 116.84391,128.7085 118.75,127.03125 C 120.65608,125.35401 121.75814,122.95183 122.09375,123.21875 C 122.71046,123.70923 122.97314,126.63867 122.15625,127.3125 C 121.33935,127.98634 120.11005,129.47029 120.1875,130.375 C 119.94544,135.25928 117.0492,133.91439 118.53125,135 C 121.12884,136.90275 121.39368,134.08685 122,132.15625 C 122.40468,130.86769 123.33181,130.31742 123.84375,130.5625 C 124.78094,131.01118 125.89875,133.23079 125.1875,134.625 C 124.04334,136.8678 122.56325,138.35426 126,137.78125 C 128.73858,137.32464 130.15846,140.69337 130.1875,144.21875 C 130.21029,146.98404 133.06977,151.81251 134.6875,151.8125 C 135.05182,151.8125 135.40793,152.01009 135.6875,152.25 z "
      />
      <path id="Kangaroo-Island" d="M 121.49204,138.51327 C 121.46821,136.73665 115.63843,136.48647 115.69496,139.03747 C 115.71911,140.12728 121.51662,140.4077 121.49204,138.51327 z " />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<div><input type=text id="highlighter"><span>Try typing "NewSouthWales", "QLD", "WA" or "VIC"</span></div>
```

Comment: H @jcuenod ! What I need is this: "Hilight the are which ID is the same as the shown word in the text box". I think I'd have the same problem with svg. I don't know how to ask that. This is what I have not using links:                                                         $('.showme').click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $('#huelva').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
            data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
            $('#huelva').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        });  // but works only in the first one #huelva

Comment: Sorry, I saw how it came out. I don't know how to put in "code mode" on the comment section.

Comment: Try the snippet now (type into the textbox).

Comment: It can work. I need to do that when clicking a button but I think I can work with that. I´m doing a geography quizz. So when I show the word Italy, if the user doesn't know where it is, they can click on the "showme" button, and Italy hilights. But when pressing continue, the word and country,state... changes so pressing the same button, I want to hilight the new place. That was driving me crazy, telling jQuery how to hilight the proper area each time. Thanks @jcuenod !!!

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm doing another thing instead. I've created as many buttons as countries and I showing them at the same time as the countries. I mean,  I don't have only one "showme" button, I have a lot, but each time I show one, and each button is linked to the right country on the map.