# classList.toggle not working

Tags: jquery, svg, toggleclass

I'm trying to toggle a cssclass using jQuery on an SVG element each time a div element is clicked.

From what I've read, there are issues doing this with SVG elements and this way was a solution:

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    $("#svg1").classList.toggle("clicked");
});`
```

However, this doesn't work. So I assumed it was due to the use of an SVG element in this function. But when replacing said SVG element with a div element, like this:

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    $("#div2").classList.toggle("clicked");
});
```

the class still won't toggle, despite there being no SVG element in the function.

Comment: Any error in your console? Does your browser support [`classList`'s `toggle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: Reading this question and its answers may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Comment: Yes, it does, I'm using Chrome, Frédéric. I got my solution from the comment posted by Tomas on that particular question, @Robert. I just found it confusing that people were claiming it to be working when it's not for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try it with plain javascript, I don't think jQuery has this method.

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('div2').classList.toggle("clicked");
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mxahxede/)

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much, @michael, sorted out the problem perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: jQuery has a method to toggle class (with animation) http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2):

Toggle class function in jQuery is toggleClass():

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    $("#div2").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```