# Cannot set property className of #X which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, svg

The full error in the browser console in this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property className of # which has only a getter

I am trying to put a class with Javascript everytime an action happens, this is the code

```js
performClick (sideBet) {
    switch (sideBet) {
    case 'SuitEmUp':
        document.getElementById('SuitEmUp').className = 'animated shake';
        break;

    case 'PerfectPairs':
        document.getElementById('PerfectPairs').className = 'animated shake';
        break;

    default:
        console.log('Sorry, we are out of ' + sideBet + '.');
    }
}
```

and then changed that code to only this in my Reactjs app

```js
performClick (sideBet) {
    this.refs[sideBet].getDOMNode().className = 'animated shake';
}
```

and the same error comes up...

HTML

```html
<div ref="sideBetsLeft">

  <svg id="PerfectPairs" onClick={this.performClick.bind(this, 'PerfectPairs')}
       ref="PerfectPairs" className="side-bet" viewBox={viewBoxVal}></svg>

  <svg id="SuitEmUp" onClick={this.performClick.bind(this, 'SuitEmUp')}
       ref="SuitEmUp" className="side-bet" viewBox={viewBoxVal}></svg>

</div>
```

So, I don't know what is going on here. Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of React  are you using?

Comment: @hex13 `"react": "0.13.3"`

Comment: maybe something SVG related? What would happen if you had <div> instead of <svg> element? There would also be an error?

Comment: @hex13 if I remove the svg and put a div instead, I can't see anything in the view.

Comment: or what if you would set class attribute instead of className: ` this.refs[sideBet].getDOMNode().setAttribute('class', 'animated shake');`?

Comment: @hex13 it works haha so weird. Post this as an answer so I can give you the best answer check.

Comment: btw. probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to set `class` attribute instead of setting property `className`:

```js
this.refs[sideBet].getDOMNode().setAttribute('class', 'animated shake');
```