# jQuery .addClass function not adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to add a class for highlighting certain elements on my web page. I'm using the `jQuery("selector").addClass("class")` function to do that. However, it does not work.

```
function toggleHighlight(selector, on) {
  if (on) {
    $(selector).addClass("highlighted");
  } else {
    $(selector).removeClass("highlighted");
  }
}
```

When the `on` argument is `true` and the `selector` argument is a valid selector, it enters the `if` clause and exits. Unfortunately the classes of the elements the selector refers to, remain unchanged. I seem to missing something fairly fundamental. Help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I left out the `console.log($(selector));` and `console.log($(".highlighted"));` statements earlier, for clarity. The first returns the right elements, the second, none (called after `.addClass()`). The elements themselves are `<path>` elements created by leaflet for a map (from GeoJSON). As such, the HTML is rather hard to reproduce.

I have called the function form a button on the page: `<input type="button" id="toggle-0702" class="btn btn-default" onClick="toggleHighlight('.node-0112', true)" value="turn on" \>` as well as directly from the JS console. Same results.

EDIT 2:

Apparently this is an issue with either `<path>` elements, or (more likely) leaflet. To demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/mrz40jgw/. Notice the `shy` class on the second circle.

Comment: can you show how you are calling `toggleHighlight`?

Comment: Can you give the html code or the values of selector and on

Comment: Are you sure the selector is valid? if you do `$(selector)` in the console in dev tools at that moment, is the returned array not empty?

Comment: it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dh13jzca/)

Comment: You should make sure that you're calling this after the dom has been loaded

Comment: How do you check that class isn't added???

Comment: Please check if your selector has the required prefix (e.g. id*,id$,#,.)

Comment: this should work. http://jsfiddle.net/h0r7bu51/ you should read the answer provided by Kendas to see why

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the problem lies with jQuery's inability to change classes on SVG elements: [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

For the record, here's my solution in light of the new information:

```
function toggleHighlight(selector, on) {
    var oldClasses = [];
    var newClasses = "";
    var elements = $(selector)
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        oldClasses = $(elements[i]).attr("class").split(" ");
        newClasses = "";
        for (var j in oldClasses) {
            if (oldClasses[j] != "highlighted") {
                newClasses += " " + oldClasses[j];
        }}
        if (on) {
            newClasses += " highlighted";
        }
        $(elements[i]).attr("class", newClasses.trim());
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

We don't have enough information to say exactly what's going on, but unless you've interferred with jQuery, we can rule out that `addClass` is broken. Thus, one of the following is likely true:

- `toggleHighlight` is not being called when you think it is. Use `console.log` to debug this.
- `$(selector)` is not yielding what you think it is. Use `console.log` to debug this.

Or perhaps most likely:

- Adding the class `highlight` does not affect the targeted elements in the manner you think it ought to, perhaps due to a selector of greater specificity. Debug this by manually setting the class and verify how that affects the visual properties of the element.

Note that jQuery already has a toggle for classes, so your code can be simplified to:

```
function toggleHighlight(selector, on) {
  $(selector).toggleClass("highlighted", on);
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up the code up a bit and in fact it originally looked more like this:

    function toggleHighlight(selector, on) {
      console.log($(selector));
      if (on) {
        $(selector).addClass("highlighted");
        console.log(".highlighted");
      } else {
        $(selector).removeClass("highlighted");
      }
    }

The first line into the log yielded a correct number of elements, the second, none.

Regarding the .toggleClass() function, I'll take that into consideration, though when I think about it, my original function might be just misnamed.