# jQuery .addClass() and SVG element

Tags: jquery, svg, addclass

I have difficulty with finding a problem with jQuerys `.addClass()` function on an `svg` element

On [this](http://multimel-nieruchomosci.pl/mieszkania/mieszkania?filter[nrbudynku]=9) site I have an svg object like this:

```
<svg ... >
<polygon  class="maska mieszkanie" id="I9M01" ... />
<polygon  class="maska mieszkanie" id="I9M02" ... />
<polygon  class="maska mieszkanie" id="I9M03" ... />
...
```

In code below I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#I9M01").addClass( "wolne" );
</script>
```

But I cannot force it to work. If I do `jQuery("#I9M01").remove()` it works, but I cannot add class and I don't know why. Is there any problem with svg elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

addClass doesn't work on svg.

You can use `.attr('class', 'wolne')`