# toggleClass is not toggling the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a class on the hover event of an element. The code that I have is

```
        var el = $('[model-id="' + node.id + '"]');

        el.hover(
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass( "myClass" );
                console.log("in",this.getAttribute("class"))
            },

            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass( "myClass" );
                console.log("out",this.getAttribute("class"))
            }
        )
```

I have the chrome tools elements tab open, and I'm looking at the dom.

When I hover over the element, I get the message

```
in element Node basic
```

and when I leave the element, I get

```
out element Node basic
```

so you can see on the "in" event, I am getting an appropriate element, and adding the "myClass" class. however, this is not appearing in the dom inspector.

What am I missing ? It must be something obvious ;)

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a working example using the code snippet functionality? Or you could make one using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: When you look in the dom inspector, is the element in the hovered state? I know you can check that on Chrome and I know I've forgotten to do so myself, personally. =)

Comment: What if you use `$(this).prop('class')` instead of `this.getAttribute('class') for debugging?

Comment: Irrelevant to the actual question, but why use `toggleClass()`? if you're adding the class on hover and removing it on mouseleave, why not just use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`? It will be slightly less processing that way.

Comment: @YoYo the comments section isn't really the place for this. Search for it or post a separate question.

Comment: I am trying to get a complete working jsfiddle - problem is the code is part of a much bigger project using jointjs. I'll try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.. you can use `hasClass` to see if the element has the class. See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLxz5qa3/)**.

```
el.hover(
    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( "myClass" );
        console.log("in",$(this).hasClass("myClass"))
    },

    function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( "myClass" );
        console.log("out",$(this).hasClass("myClass"))
    }
)
```

if you actually wanted to get the class and not just test that it was added. Then you can use `$(this).attr("class")`.

Comment: using hasClass returns

    in false
    out false

Comment: why don't you use addClass/removeClass? i don't understand what the point is of toggleClass in your code. you know the exact states your elements are going to be in. (on/off). Just remove the jquery magic and do the toggle yourself. rule out as much randomness as you can. you could even go straight javascript without jquery. my suspicion is that "this" isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out that the element I was trying to add a class to was within an svg tag. According to [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass) this won't work.

The answer is to either use jQuery3 or use the classList object

```
this.classList.add('myClass');
```

does indeed change the DOM

hope this helps someone else looking for the solution to a strange problem!