# Trigger CSS transition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JavaScript and got a simple problem here:
I want to trigger an CSS animation (Spin the blue nut) when another element is hovered via JavaSript ONLY.

This is what I've got so far, and I don't know what I'm missing in this snippet:

```js
$('#menu').hover(
  function () {
    $('#nut').addClass('spin');
  },
  function () {
    $('#nut').removeClass('spin');
  }
);
```

```css
#nut {
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.spin {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="menu" x="0px" y="0px" width="71.39px" height="71.39px" viewBox="0 0 71.39 71.39" enable-background="new 0 0 71.39 71.39" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon id="nut" fill="#0000ff" points="66.605,53.541 35.694,71.388 4.784,53.541 4.784,17.849 35.694,0.002 66.605,17.849"/>
</svg>
```

I really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing missing is jquery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="menu" x="0px" y="0px" width="71.39px" height="71.39px" viewBox="0 0 71.39 71.39" enable-background="new 0 0 71.39 71.39" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon id="nut" fill="#0000ff" points="66.605,53.541 35.694,71.388 4.784,53.541 4.784,17.849 35.694,0.002 66.605,17.849"/>
</svg>
```

Take a look at this code working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/j2bon1gc/

Actually it not only lacked Jquery, but in order to work it specially lacked a jquery version greater than 2.2, which was the version that implemented this feature.

Take a look here: [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

And in the Meta question I opened for this: [Why isn't jQuery working in this question's code snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322366/why-isnt-jquery-working-in-this-questions-code-snippet)

Comment: Works great but this might sound weird... I don't get the same effect installing jQuery on the snippet  O_o (See edited post)

Comment: it should be only some url access thing.

Comment: It should have worked. I opened a question in meta about this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322366/why-isnt-jquery-working-in-this-questions-code-snippet