# Add CSS styling to SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG in which i want to add a particular styling to all circle having r="5"

```
<div class="svgchart">
    <svg width="1190" height="390">
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="400" r="40" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="400" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle " cx="400" cy="400" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>  
</div>
```

I have tried this but does not work

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble-plot-chart-circle");

for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    if(element.getAttribute("r") === "5") {
        // it takes the initial inline style which was applied at the time of crating the SVG
        element.setAttribute("opacity", "0 !important");// does not work for SVG  
        element.addClass("test"); // does not work for SVG 
    } 
}
```

can any one help me on this as i am new to SVG

Comment: Is `addClass` defined in your script? Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: no...i was trying the normal jquery addClass

Comment: `svg .bubble-plot-chart-circle[r="5"] { /* your css */ }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Comment: !important is invalid within a presentation attribute it they won't override a CSS style rule that is applied to an element, it can override less specific CSS style rules though such as a rule that applies to a class or to all elements.

Comment: @Rakesh - you can access the native methods with: `elem.classList.add`, `elem.classList.remove`, `elem.classList.contains`, `elem.classList.toggle`

Answer (score 2):

Try this once:

I used `querySelectorAll` to get the filtered elements with provided class name and attribute.

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".bubble-plot-chart-circle[r='5']");   // filtering as required

for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    element.setAttribute("opacity", "0");  // !important is invalid in presentation attribute (check comment above)
    element.classList.add("test");         // JavaScript's method instead of jquery's addClass method
}
```

and also `addClass` method is not available for JavaScript DOM object. It  is available for jQuery object. If you want to use `addClass` method, convert the DOM object to jquery object as shown below:

```
var jqueryElement = $(element);
jqueryElement.addClass('test');
```

And also, you can do the same selection using CSS as well:

```
.bubble-plot-chart-circle[r='5'] {
     /* SVG styles here */
}
```

Comment: how can i pass a variable in .var count= 5;  
bubble-plot-chart-circle[r='count']??

Comment: @Rakesh I didn't get you.

Comment: var test =5 ; 
document.querySelectorAll(".bubble-plot-chart-circle[r= " + test + " ]");
how to pass the variable test to this syntax??


I tried this
document.querySelectorAll(".bubble-plot-chart-circle[r="+test+"]");

but gettign error in console

Comment: @Rakesh try this `document.querySelectorAll(".bubble-plot-chart-circle[r='" +  test + "']");`

Comment: i tried this 
var element = document.querySelectorAll(".bubble-plot-chart-circle");
var jqueryElement = $(element);
jqueryElement.addClass('test');

but does not work...is their any syntax mistake?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns list of elements. You can't convert list to jquery object. So use `$('.bubble-plot-chart-circle')`. Don't use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @enhzflep OP wanted with jQuery.

Comment: Note that you need jQuery 3.0 or later if you want to use `addClass` with SVG elements. https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#feature-svg-documents-support-class-operations

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code does work. What doesn't work, is your attribute.

I think you should look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity

This works in plunker:

```
<body>
    <div class="svgchart">
    <svg width="1190" height="390">
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="400" r="40" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="400" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle " cx="400" cy="400" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>  
    </div>
    <script>
    var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble-plot-chart-circle");

    for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        var element = allElements[i];

        element.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0");  
    }

    </script>
  </body>
```

You can filter elements by attribute as you do. However, you need to wait till content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Its working. See this. Use `element.classList.add()` instead:

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble-plot-chart-circle");

  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    if (element.getAttribute("r") === "5") {

         element.classList.add("test");
      
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  opacity: 0.3 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgchart">
  <svg width="1190" height="390">
    <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue"></circle>
    <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="100" cy="200" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle " cx="100" cy="300" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A short D3 solution (since you have the `d3js` tag in your question), using `selection` and `filter`:

```
var circles = d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(){
return d3.select(this).attr("r") == 5;});
```

And that's all you need: `circles` is a selection containing all the circles with a 5-pixel radius.

Once we have the proper selection, we can manipulate it the way we want. For instance, making all these circles moving to the right:

```
circles.transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");
```

Here is a demo snippet:

```js
var circles = d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(){
return d3.select(this).attr("r") == 5;});
circles.transition().delay(500).duration(1000).attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
 <svg width="390" height="390">
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="20" cy="40" r="40" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="100" cy="40" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle " cx="140" cy="40" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achive using d3.js. please find the answer below

```js
var circle = d3.selectAll('.bubble-plot-chart-circle');
circle._groups.forEach(function(t){
    t.forEach(function(e){
    if(d3.select(e).attr("r") == 5){
     d3.select(e).style('fill','red')
    }})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="svgchart">
    <svg width="500" height="310">
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle  class="bubble-plot-chart-circle" cx="400" cy="200" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle class="bubble-plot-chart-circle " cx="400" cy="250" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS makes this pretty easy.

```
circle[r="5"]{
  fill: #f12222;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/daveycakes/pen/RGZVPv

Remember, these are html elements with attributes; it doesn't have to get so weird.